# String causing a Parse Error that doesn't exist in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing

I keep getting the following parse error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.
>
> Source Error:
>
> > Line 1:  ate
>
> Source File: /admin/JobCategories.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

Problem is, the file in question doesn't have that string ("ate") anywhere in it. I did a search in visual studio for it, and found one file containing it.

Strangely enough, the file was shown as JobCategories(1).aspx. I opened it, and tru enough the string was appended to the start of the file. I deleted it, but the error persists, and now when I search for the string in VS I find no results. Tried restarting IIS, rebuilding the website in VS, and restoring an older version of the file from backup that used to work, but I still get the same error.

Only thing done on the file since the last backup was updating a string in the HTML, nothing to do with the code, and nothing near the beginning of the file.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You probably copy/pasted stuff from word... JobC**ate**gories

Comment: Are you sure that all code is inside content place holder? <asp:Content>Add your HTML here</asp:Content>

Comment: Try "Rebuild Solution" in VS - It could be that it's not recompiled from the change.

Comment: @leppie thanks, but no; nothing came from Word (not even installed here).

Comment: @SainPradeep thank you, yes, this was the first thing we checked.

Comment: @Dan that could be it. will try (some errors are preventing a rebuild) and update. I appreciate the help.